# Django template variable not being rendered into JavaScript

Tags: javascript, django

I have the following Javascript between  tags in a template:

```
YAHOO.util.Event.addListener(window, "load", function() {
YAHOO.example.Taco = function() {
    var myColumnDefs = [
        {% for field in included_fields %}
           {key:"{{ field }}", sortable:true, resizeable:true},
        {% endfor %}
    ];

    var myDataSource = new YAHOO.util.XHRDataSource("http://192.168.1.15:5555/yuidt/list");
    myDataSource.responseType = YAHOO.util.DataSource.TYPE_JSON;
    myDataSource.responseSchema = {
        resultsList: "people",
        fields : [ {{field_list}} ]
    };

    var myDataTable = new YAHOO.widget.DataTable("basic",
            myColumnDefs, myDataSource, {caption:"DataTable Caption"});

    return {
        oDS: myDataSource,
        oDT: myDataTable
    };
}();
```

});

The value of field_list is the string "first","last","phone"

fields is getting set to nothing some how. So `{{field_list}}` seems to not be getting rendered.

In the body on the page I have `<p>{{field_list}}</p>` which displays "first","last","phone" as expected.

This makes me think it is some sort of escaping issue, I tried |addslashes but that was no help.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: This could be useful to debug this: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#how-invalid-variables-are-handled.
Furthermore are you sure there's no block tag around the code you show us that may cause this problem?

Comment: For what it's worth, use the `safe` filter to turn off any autoescaping of a string.  I really doubt that will fix your problem though.

Comment: What does the rendered JS look like if you view source?  Any chance something is wrong with the Javascript itself?

Comment: Eric: The safe filter was the solution, thanks. If you post it as the answer I'll happily give you the credit.

Comment: sdolan: Thanks, to you as well. That was what lead to the above solution, I'm not quite sure how I failed to do that before I posted here. Long day I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Eric said it can be resolved using safe filter !